# Multiple group counts within data base

Tags: python, pandas

I have been presented with a very small dataset that has the `date` of each time a `user` logs into a system, I have to use this data set to create a table where I can show for each log-in the cumulative monthly counts of logs and the overall cumulative counts of logs, this is the data set I have:

| date | user |
| --- | --- |
| 1/01/2022 | Mark |
| 2/01/2022 | Mark |
| 3/02/2022 | Mark |
| 4/02/2022 | Mark |
| 5/03/2022 | Mark |
| 6/03/2022 | Mark |
| 7/03/2022 | Mark |
| 8/03/2022 | Mark |
| 9/03/2022 | Mark |

and this is my desired output:

| row | date | user | monthly_track | acum_track |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/01/2022 | Mark | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2/01/2022 | Mark | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3/02/2022 | Mark | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 4/02/2022 | Mark | 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 5/03/2022 | Mark | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | 6/03/2022 | Mark | 2 | 6 |
| 7 | 7/03/2022 | Mark | 3 | 7 |
| 8 | 8/03/2022 | Mark | 4 | 8 |
| 9 | 9/03/2022 | Mark | 5 | 9 |

**Why?** Let's look at the row number 5. This is the first time the user Mark has logged into the system during the month 3 (March) but it is the 5th overall login in the data set (for the purpose of learning there will only be one year (2022).

I have no idea as to how to get the monthly and overall count together. I can `groupby` `user` and `sort` by `date` to count how many times in total a user has logged in, but I know that in order to achive my desired output I will have to group by `date` and `user` and then make counts based on month but I will have to somehow group the data by user (only) to get the overall count and I dont think I could group twice the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to convert `date` to actual `datetime` values with `to_datetime`. The rest is simple with `groupby` and `cumcount`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['monthly_count'] = df.groupby([df['user'], df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month]).cumcount() + 1
df['acum_count'] = df.groupby('user').cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        date  user  monthly_count  acum_count
0 2022-01-01  Mark              1           1
1 2022-01-02  Mark              2           2
2 2022-02-03  Mark              1           3
3 2022-02-04  Mark              2           4
4 2022-03-05  Mark              1           5
5 2022-03-06  Mark              2           6
6 2022-03-07  Mark              3           7
7 2022-03-08  Mark              4           8
8 2022-03-09  Mark              5           9
```